# Losing votes despite being over the 200 rep limit

Tags: support, reputation, deletion, deleted-accounts

I was a little surprised to have found that I lost 132 rep due to some user that was deleted (!).  What I do not understand, however, is that this has happened on a day that I am (so far) 17 votes beyond the 20 of the daily limit, and yet I still lost the rep.  How does this work?

Comment: Perhaps you should check your reputation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation).  You will probably see, that there you have 200 reputation points today. The upvotes of the removed users have been removed from the days where day have been cast. But on your profile the decrease is shown today, since the user has been removed today.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I think Willie explained it well enough.  I just found it confusing, that's all.  And a little jarring that I could lose that much from a single event.  Yikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user is deleted, his up/down votes are undone.

This happens as often as users request to be deleted.

Comment: That's not my question.  My question is, why did I lose the rep despite having +170 beyond the daily limit?  Isn't there a rep bank for the day in case of that?  Or was the deleted user responsible for all those upvotes?

Comment: When a user is deleted, it is like those votes he cast never existed in the first place. It is not `-132 rep` from _today_, it is `-132 rep` from way back when. So it will not affect, in anyway, your reputation cap, unless said user has awarded you some reputation today.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, but that's not how it appears.  On today's tally, it looks like I just got +113 for the day.

Comment: @RonGordon if you had, in fact, a day sometime in the past where you hit the 200 barrier and went past, and that said user gave you some upvotes on _that day_, then the reputation recalculation will factor this in. But your rep gain today will not be affected.

Comment: @RonGordon that... is unfortunate. Maybe it can be raised as a UI bug.

Comment: @WillieWong: yeah, definitely confusing.  But the system as you describe it makes perfect sense.  Where could I submit a bug?

Comment: @WillieWong: not to whine further, but I just got a solution accepted, yet my rep score did not increase.  A bug?

Comment: If you are past the 200 point daily limit, you do not receive points for getting the solution accepted.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That's not the system used to behave (as recently as a week or so ago even). Is this a recent change?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: are you sure? I think answers are immune (which is why he can have +113 from today net despite the -132 from user deletion)

Comment: @RonGordon: for bugs just post a new post to either here or to meta.stackoverflow.com and apply the (bug) tag. Also, try visiting [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) and trigger a reputation recalculation if you haven't. You had 4 accepted answers from today but it looked like only 3 of them were counted in the net reputation gain. If that doesn't work, [contact the SE team](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/other) and they will either sort it out for you or explain the subtlety that Alex and I have overlooked.

Comment: @WillieWong: thanks for the help.  The trigger did nothing, so I sent a help request and will hopefully hear back soon.

Comment: @RonGordon: maybe someone unaccepted one of your answers? I checked again now and it looks like there are only 3 accepted answers from today, making the total correct.

Comment: @WillieWong: yeah, it looks like it.  But there was a snapshot in time when that answer was accepted and still no movement.  Oh well, easy come easy go.

Answer (score 2):

That's by design. You can only recover these points by accepted answers, bounties, etc.

Anything which isn't limited by the cap itself.